# Jquery get value of element loaded with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page with 2 select boxes, one of which is loaded by an AJAX call. I then want to validate the elements with jquery before I enable the submit button. The jquery works fine when I change the static select (strDirectorate) but not when I change the one loaded by AJAX (new_cc).

Is it because jquery is getting the value of new_cc as it was when the page was loaded?

```
      <div class="selectfield">
        <select id="strDirectorate" name="strDirectorate" class="mainform_select" onChange="getNewCostCentre(this.value)">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <?php do {  ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_rsLocality['strLocalityShort']?>" <?php if($row_rsLocality['strLocalityShort'] == $strDirectorate){ echo $selected; } ?>><?php echo $row_rsLocality['strLocalityLong']?></option>
            <?php
                } while ($row_rsLocality = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsLocality));
                    $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsLocality);
                if($rows > 0) {
                    mysql_data_seek($rsLocality, 0);
                    $row_rsLocality = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsLocality);
                }
            ?>        
        </select>
        </div>


        <div id="txtNewCostCentre" class="selectfield">
        <select id="new_cc" name="new_cc" class="mainform_select" onChange="getNewPosition(this.value)">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" name="submit_button" class="styled_button" value="Submit" />
        </div>
```

The function getNewCostCentre is

```
function getNewCostCentre(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtNewCostCentre").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
document.getElementById("txtNewCostCentre").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getNewCostCentre.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The code for getNewCostCentre.php is

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `tblcostcentreorganisation` WHERE `strOrganisation` LIKE '363 ".addslashes($dir)."%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(isset($_GET["q"])){
    $display_string = '<select id="new_cc" name="new_cc" class="mainform_select" onChange="getNewPosition(this.value)" style="background-color:#F8E0E0">';
    $display_string .= '<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option>';
}else{
    $display_string = '<select id="new_cc" name="new_cc" class="mainform_select" onChange="getNewPosition(this.value)">';
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $cc = substr($row['strCostCentre'], 3, strlen($row['strCostCentre'])-3) . " " . substr($row['strOrganisation'], 3, strlen($row['strOrganisation'])-3);
  $org_name = $row['strOrganisation'];

  if ($org == $org_name){
      $display_string .= '<option value="'.$org_name.'" selected="selected">'.$cc.'</option>';
  }else{
      $display_string .= '<option value="'.$org_name.'">'.$cc.'</option>';
  }
  }

$display_string .= '</select>';

echo $display_string;
```

And the jquery validation is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.selectfield select').change(function() {

        var empty = false;

        $('.selectfield select').each(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#F8E0E0");
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('.actions input').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
});
});
```

The onload code is as follows. I assume it's because I'm using .load within (after) .onload?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.onload = function(){

    //Load directorate, cost centre and position
    if ($('#hid_stage').val() == "Rejected") {
        var str = $('#hid_criteria').val();
        strencoded = encodeURIComponent(str);
        $('#txtNewCostCentre').load("getNewCostCentre.php?cr="+strencoded);
        $('#txtNewPosition').load("getNewPosition_ba.php?cr="+strencoded);
    }

    var empty = false;

    $('.selectfield select').each(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#F8E0E0");
                empty = true;
            }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('.actions input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Why is `getNewCostCentre()` not wrutten with jQuery's AJAX functions? If you're including jQuery, use it

Comment: Fair point - because I added jquery at a later date. I should amend it to use jquery AJAX. It doesn't answer my question though (or does it??).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding your `change` handler for `$('.selectfield select'`) when the page loads.  This attaches the handler to all elements that match that selector.

If you then change this element, it won't have the handler attached.

Instead, you should use the `live` handler, to match all elements that exist now or are ever created in the future.

```
$('.selectfield select').live("change", function() {
 ...
});
```

UPDATE:

For you onload issue, it would be far easier not to repeat your code.  If you need to fire off the validation after loading the content dynamically, then trigger the change event once the load has finished - like the following example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Load directorate, cost centre and position
    if ($('#hid_stage').val() == "Rejected") {
        var str = $('#hid_criteria').val();
        strencoded = encodeURIComponent(str);
        $('#txtNewCostCentre').load("getNewCostCentre.php?cr="+strencoded, function() {
            $('.selectfield select').trigger("change");
        });
        $('#txtNewPosition').load("getNewPosition_ba.php?cr="+strencoded);
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks devrooms. I've also got some .onload validation which seems to having the same problem. I've amended my question.

Comment: Thanks x 2 for your help. Works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

An ajax update of the input shouldn't trigger the javascript change event so the handler you've specified in change won't get called.

From the javascript specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html) :

> onchange = script [CT] The onchange event occurs when a control loses
>   the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus.
>   This attribute applies to the following elements: INPUT, SELECT, and
>   TEXTAREA.

I'd suggest performing the validation logic in the same part of your javascript where you're handling the response from the ajax request. Right after the line

```
document.getElementById("txtNewCostCentre").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

add the call

```
validate();
```

Where validate is earlier defined as :

```
function validate() {
    var empty = false;

    $('.selectfield select').each(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#F8E0E0");
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('.actions input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

So that your jquery validation becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.selectfield select').change(validate());
```

Comment: Completely agree with @Bojangles that you should be consistently using jquery. In this case I wouldn't be surprised if jquery fired off a javascript event in response to you using it to modify the contents of the element.

Comment: I don't want the AJAX call to trigger the change event. It should be triggered by the user. Devroom's answer solved my problem. Thanks for the input nonetheless.